# Calculate font dimensions inside a input in Selenium.Net

Tags: c#, selenium

I've got a text input, in which I'm typing text using selenium. I would like to type some text and than click on a known position inside one of the words (so that the cursor moves there, and there is a click event).

For example, I type "hello there", than I click after "hello t" and type letter "h" so the input text becomes "hello there".

How do I do this with Selenium.Net?

I'm mostly working with Selenium.Net, but any language will do.

Comment: to simulate user making and correcting errors

Comment: What about use left arrow key to navigate?